# How do I move an element with mouse event movement without changing its size in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a custom element representing a window in an operating system. Like a window, it should be moveable/draggable. I can successfully move the window with this code:

```
moveVertically(movement) {
  const boundingClientRect = this.getBoundingClientRect()
  this.setTop(boundingClientRect.top + movement)
  this.setBottom(boundingClientRect.bottom + movement)
}

moveHorizontally(movement) {
  const boundingClientRect = this.getBoundingClientRect()
  this.setLeft(boundingClientRect.left + movement)
  this.setRight(boundingClientRect.right + movement)
}
```

The argument `movement` is mouse event variable movementY and movementX, respectively. The problem is that, if I move the window to quickly, it resizes as well.

How do I move the window without resizing it?

Edit: With this code:

```
moveVertically(movement) {
  const boundingClientRect = this.getBoundingClientRect()
  this.style.transform =
    `translateY(${boundingClientRect.top + movement}px)`
}

moveHorizontally(movement) {
  const boundingClientRect = this.getBoundingClientRect()
  this.style.transform = 
  `translateX(${boundingClientRect.left + movement}px)`
}
```

the window  kind of just moves up and down, when I try to move it. If I comment one of the methods out, it works perfectly, but I can't get both to work at the same time.

I haven't changed my resizing method yet, but that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Only manipulate top+left OR bottom+right. If you manipulate the coordinates of the same axis at the same time (top + bottom OR left + right) you will cause the size of the element to change. I'd recommend top+left to keep things simple. Also, I'd always recommend using CSS translate instead of manipulate position using top/right/bottom/left. It handles sub pixel values better.

Comment: @Terry I used right and bottom in my resize method, so that resizing doesn't move the window, so if I leave out left and bottom from the move method, those values remain the same.

Should I rely on something else in my resize method, then?

I shall look into CSS translate.

Comment: You should simply give your window a pre-determined width and height, and then set its top/left to 0: then just use CSS transform to manipulate its XY positioning.

Comment: @Terry See my edit, if you will continue helping me.

Comment: Your transforms are overriding each other. Consider either using CSS custom properties or storing the X and Y translations in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your second attempt doesn't work is because you are overwriting the CSS transform. You will need to persist the values on either axis: this can be done by using CSS custom properties for example.

The example below is an adapted example based on your code. The `--translate-x` and `--translate-y` are CSS custom properties that can be adjusted individually and they are simply being assigned to the CSS `transform` property using `transform: translate(var(--translate-x, 0), var(--translate-y, 0));` (the fallback value is set to 0):

```js
const stage = document.querySelector('#stage');
const el = document.querySelector('#el');

function moveVertically(movement) {
  el.style.setProperty('--translate-y', `${movement}px`);
}

function moveHorizontally(movement) {
  el.style.setProperty('--translate-x', `${movement}px`);
}

stage.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  moveHorizontally(e.clientX);
  moveVertically(e.clientY);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#stage {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#el {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  transform: translate(var(--translate-x, 0), var(--translate-y, 0));
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
  <div id="el"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can also store the XY coordinates into a variable:

```js
const stage = document.querySelector('#stage');
const el = document.querySelector('#el');

const elCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };

function moveVertically(movement) {
  elCoords.y = movement;
}

function moveHorizontally(movement) {
  elCoords.x = movement;
}

stage.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  moveHorizontally(e.clientX);
  moveVertically(e.clientY);
  
  el.style.transform = `translate(${elCoords.x}px, ${elCoords.y}px)`;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#stage {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#el {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
  <div id="el"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, of course. I saw a video about transform yesterday, and overwriting was specifically mentioned, along with variables. I guess I thought that I didn't have to worry about it, because I used different functions.